# `h!` table placement with `H` spacing?

Tags: tables, floats, minipage, line-spacing

So I'm trying to make an entirelty double-spaced document, so I have the following code in a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{2}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{float}


%Document Begins
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        Table 1:\setcounter{table}{1}\\\emph{Demographic and clinical information for each of the neglect participants.}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccc}
            \toprule
            Patient&Age&Weeks post stroke&Gender&Regions affected by CVA\\
            \midrule
            AK&34&4&F&MCA\\
            AS&58&18&F&Parietal 1\\
            GJ&42&4&M&MCA\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \emph{Note:} MCA $=$ Territory of the Middle Cerebral Artery.
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Which, as you may see, does not produce double spacing in the minipage.  However, if I change `h!` to `H`, it produces double spacing everywhere (which is desired).  However, I would prefer to use h! as it positions the table in a cleaner place in my document.

Does anyone know why this happens, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Why are you using  minipages anyway?  \setcounter is global.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am using minipages because my school's psychology department is very particular about formatting, and has told us to put two captions on the top and bottom of the table.  I couldn't figure out how to do it, so I just put two minipages and a tabular environment within a table, and they all stayed together and worked well ish.

Comment: if you really want a document that has doublespacing everywhere, don't use the setspace package but do `\def\baselinestretch {2}`, this will then also affect float and footnotes.

Comment: the minipage are doing nothing useful here, the parts will always stay together anyway as a `table` makes an unbreakable box.

Comment: also why number the table "by hand" in this way? `Table 1:\setcounter{table}{1}` seems a very strange construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `\def\arraystretch{2}` before \begin{document}. If you choose 2, you get something like this using [h!]:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I know about this, however, notice that there is not double spacing between `Table 1:` and `Demographic...`.

Comment: A fix would be, that instead of  "\ \" you use "\par\bigskip" before \emph

Answer (score 2):

The setspace package tries hard *not* to make everything double spaced. It reverts to single spacing e.g. in floats and footnotes. If you don't want this, don't use the package but set \baselinestretch manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch {2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%Document Begins
\begin{document}
\lipsum[13] \footnote{\lipsum[13]}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        Table 1:\setcounter{table}{1}\\\emph{Demographic and clinical information for each of the neglect participants.}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccc}
            \toprule
            Patient&Age&Weeks post stroke&Gender&Regions affected by CVA\\
            \midrule
            AK&34&4&F&MCA\\
            AS&58&18&F&Parietal 1\\
            GJ&42&4&M&MCA\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \emph{Note:} MCA $=$ Territory of the Middle Cerebral Artery.
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]